# Access nested objects

Tags: javascript, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to access the nested ingredients object within the main entry. The output from the `{{recipe.ingredients}}` tag is `[object Object],[object Object]`. What do I need to put in order for the `{{recipe.ingredients}}` to output the name and amount?

Object from a database

```json
{
  "_id": "zSetYKmvv2HB6v8hJ",
  "name": "Grilled Cheese",
  "desc": "Sandwich",
  "ingredients": [{
    "name": "Bread",
    "amount": "2 Slices"
  }, {
    "name": "Cheese",
    "amount": "Lots"
  }],
  "author": "ttpbGPgzDnqwN8Gg7",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-27T22:53:17.729Z",
  "inMenu": false
}
```

Code

```html
<template name="RecipeSingle">
  <h1>{{recipe.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{recipe.desc}}</p>
  <p>{{recipe.ingredients}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: That's an array, you probably want to iterate over that array

Comment: The very first example on [Blaze's documentation](https://www.meteor.com/blaze) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: recipe.ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => console.log(ingredient.name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `ingredients` are an array of objects, you will need to use meteors collection syntax to render the item set. As @Félix Saparelli mentioned in a comment, there is a good example of that [here](https://www.meteor.com/blaze). For example:

```
<div class="RecipeList">
    <ul>
        {{#each recipe.ingredients}}
        <li>
            <h1>{{name}}</h1>
            <p>{{amount}}</p>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I now understand that I wasn't trying to access another object but yet an array. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
recipe.ingredients[0].name // Will output Bread
recipe.ingredients[1].name // Will output 2 Slices
```

`ingredients` is an array, and probably iterating over it will give you all the `ingrident's name and amount.`

```js
var recipe = {
  "_id": "zSetYKmvv2HB6v8hJ",
  "name": "Grilled Cheese",
  "desc": "Sandwich",
  "ingredients": [{
    "name": "Bread",
    "amount": "2 Slices"
  }, {
    "name": "Cheese",
    "amount": "Lots"
  }],
  "author": "ttpbGPgzDnqwN8Gg7",
  "createdAt": "2015-12-27T22:53:17.729Z",
  "inMenu": false
};

recipe.ingredients.forEach(function(el, i){

  alert("Ingredient "+i+": "+el.name+", "+el.amount);
  
});
```