# Access nested members in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I'm trying to access members in a json, however I am running into some trouble. Here is an example of one of the json objects, stored in var obj:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = [
  {
    "_id": "52d7f816f96d7f6f31fbb680",
    "regNum": "0361300035313000002",
    "sd": "2013-01-01T00:00:00",
    "pd": "2013-01-25T09:30:29Z",
    "prd": "2012-12-18",
    "p": 1395000000,
    "pt": [
      {
        "name": name here",
        "price": 1395000000,
        "OKDP": {
          "code": "5520109",
          "name": "name here"
        },
        "sid": "25484812",
        "sum": "1395000000",
        "OKEI": {
          "code": "796",
          "name": "name two"
        },
        "quantity": "1"
      }
    ],
    "b": 0,
    "c": 0,
    "s": 0
  }
];
```

I'm trying to access the *sid* and *sum* values, by doing the following:

```
var sid = [];
var sum = [];

obj.forEach(block => {
  var sidOut = block.pt.sid;
  var sumOut = block.pt.sum;

  sid.push(sidOut);
  sum.push(sumOut);

});

console.log(sid);
console.log(sum);
```

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485768/access-nested-objects), however, when I run these it gives me            [ undefined ] errors.

Why am I unable to access this two values?

Comment: `block.pt[0].sid;` ; mind your 1-element arrays

Comment: @dandavis whoops! That was it, thanks. Feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you see your pt is an array of an object [{}] so you need to select which element you want to access so

```
var sidOut = block.pt[0].sid;
var sumOut = block.pt[0].sum;
```

should get you the right result